# showing newline in label

Tags: c#, html

I want to show new line in label using c# but it's not working in every browser.

I want to show in xml format in browser.

My Code as below

lblSaleData.Text ="" + "\n" + "" + eml + "" + "";

Comment: `<br />` it is so cold today....

Comment: "every browser"?? So it it a lable or browser?

Comment: Not every browser but in many browser support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This It ll work in most browser..

```
lblSaleData.Text = "&lt;Sales&gt;" + "<br/>" + 
"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;eml&gt;" + eml + 
"&lt;/eml&gt;" + "<br/>"+ "&lt;/Sales&gt;";
```

Comment: SO swallowed your BR's! I'll try fix :)

Answer (score 2):

`<br />` for line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces this result (in the HTML):

```
<Sales>
<eml>eml_value</eml></Sales>
```

The browser should interpret any whitespaces (including line breaks, as a single space), so it would probably display like (in the browser)

```
<Sales> <eml>eml_value</eml></Sales>
```

using a HTML tag that is designed for line breaks (
) forces the browser to insert a break where you want it, so

```
lblSaleData.Text ="<Sales>" + "<br / >" + "<eml>" + eml + "</eml>" + "</Sales>";
```

will yield

```
<Sales>
<eml>eml_value</eml></Sales>
```

in the browser

Comment: How the browser might choke on the <sales> and <eml> tags is another story :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want an HTML line break, use `<br />` as suggested.

If what you want is to show nicely laid-out HTML source in a label, use `System.Environment.Newline`. I normally stick it as a static readonly string `NL` at the top of a file.

Comment: Meh, stop using IE6. It's not worth the hassle you'll have supporting it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're printing out XML on the screen, right? The Label control is automatically HTML-Encoding your text, so that the angle brackets aren't treated as html elements.

The newline character doesn't show on the screen, because `<br />` is the correct html element for a newline.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
lblSaleData.Text =String.Format("&lt;Sales&gt;<br />&lt;eml&gt;{0}&lt;/eml&gt;&lt;/Sales&gt;",eml);
```

Answer (score 0):

"Line1" + "< br / >" + "Line 2" will do the trick.